# Group by one column and show the availability of specific values from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have this dataframe:

```
df1:

  drug_id      illness 
    lexapro.1     HD
    lexapro.1     MS
    lexapro.2     HDED
    lexapro.2     MS
    lexapro.2     MS
    lexapro.3     CD
    lexapro.3     Sweat
    lexapro.4     HD
    lexapro.5     WD
    lexapro.5     FN
```

I am going to first group the data based on drug_id, and search for availability of HD, MS, and FN in the illness column. Then fill in the second data frame like this:

```
df2:
drug_id       HD      MS    FN
lexapro.1      1      1      0
lexapro.2      0      1      0   
lexapro.3      0      0      0
lexapro.4      1      0      0
lexapro.5      0      0      1
```

This is my code for grouping.

```
df1.groupby('drug_id', sort=False).isin('HD')
```

but I do not know how I can assign 1 to the `F2['HD']` for each drug_id, if the `'HD'` was available for that `drug_id` in `df1`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**
`crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(df.drug_id, df.illness)[['HD', 'MS', 'FN']].ge(1).astype(int)

illness    HD  MS  FN
drug_id              
lexapro.1   1   1   0
lexapro.2   0   1   0
lexapro.3   0   0   0
lexapro.4   1   0   0
lexapro.5   0   0   1
```

---

**Option 2**
`groupby` + `value_counts` + `unstack`

```
df.groupby('drug_id').illness.value_counts()\
     .unstack()[['HD', 'MS', 'FN']].ge(1).astype(int)

illness    HD  MS  FN
drug_id              
lexapro.1   1   1   0
lexapro.2   0   1   0
lexapro.3   0   0   0
lexapro.4   1   0   0
lexapro.5   0   0   1
```

---

**Option 3**
`get_dummies` + `sum`

```
df.set_index('drug_id').illness.str.get_dummies()\
          .sum(level=0)[['HD', 'MS', 'FN']].ge(1).astype(int)

           HD  MS  FN
drug_id              
lexapro.1   1   1   0
lexapro.2   0   1   0
lexapro.3   0   0   0
lexapro.4   1   0   0
lexapro.5   0   0   1
```

Thanks to Scott Boston for the improvement!

Comment: Alternative to Option 3 `df.set_index('drug_id').illness.str.get_dummies().sum(level=0)[['HD','MS','FN']].ge(1).astype(int)`

Comment: @COLDSPEED, thank you. I tried the three types of codes you wrote, but they reorganize the drug id_column. The size of my data column is 805 rows and it includes other drugs names (Effexor, zoloft, ...). Is there any way to avoid it ? Thanks again.

Comment: @Mary If you're doing a groupby, then `df.groupby('drug_id', sort=False)` should prevent the keys from being sorted.

Answer (score 2):

```
df.groupby(['drug_id','illness']).illness.count().unstack(-1).reindex_axis(['HD', 'MS', 'FN'],axis=1).ge(0).astype(int)
Out[276]: 
illness    HD  MS  FN
drug_id              
lexapro.1   1   1   0
lexapro.2   0   1   0
lexapro.3   0   0   0
lexapro.4   1   0   0
lexapro.5   0   0   1
```

Comment: thank you. Is there any way to say, for example, if the value for illness was  HD or CD , then the value of column HD ( in df2) is 1 ? or if the value is FN or HDED, then the value for FN in the df2 is 1?  I can create a new question, if you think it is better. Thanks.

Comment: @Mary it is better create a new one , and show your expected out put