# Grouping data and searching for sets of values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

This is the data frame:

```
drug_id      illness 
    lexapro.1     HD
    lexapro.1     MS
    lexapro.2     HDED
    lexapro.2     MS
    lexapro.2     MS
    lexapro.3     CD
    lexapro.3     Sweat
    lexapro.4     HD
    lexapro.5     WD
    lexapro.5     FN
```

First, I am going to group the data based on drug_id, and search for availability of HD, Sweat, WD, CD,  MS, and FN in the illness column. Then if illness values are "HD or Sweat or WD", the column "HD" in df2 will receive 1, if the illness values in F1 were MS or HDED, then the MS column in df2 will receive 1, and if illness in FN is 1, then FN in df2 will receive 1. So df2 is like this:

```
df2:
drug_id       HD      MS    FN
lexapro.1      1      1      0
lexapro.2      0      1      0   
lexapro.3      1      0      0
lexapro.4      1      0      0
lexapro.5      1      0      1
```

I already asked a similar question. however in that question,there were no "or" in searching for values in the column illness. 
[grouping data in a data-frame, checking for availability of specific values, and updating the second data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46550638/grouping-data-in-a-data-frame-checking-for-availability-of-specific-values-and)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with a `replace` call:

```
repl_dict = {'Sweat' : 'HD', 'WD': 'HD', 'HDED' : 'MS'}
df.illness = df.illness.replace(repl_dict)
```

Now, use any of the options from your previous answer.

```
df.set_index('drug_id').illness.str.get_dummies()\
         .sum(level=0).ge(1).astype(int).drop('CD', 1)

           FN  HD  MS
drug_id              
lexapro.1   0   1   1
lexapro.2   0   0   1
lexapro.3   0   1   0
lexapro.4   0   1   0
lexapro.5   1   1   0
```

---

[piRSquared shortened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46553916/grouping-data-searching-for-a-set-of-variables-and-updating-values-in-second/46554006?noredirect=1#comment80062430_46554006) the `replace`ment and `groupby` to a single line:

```
df.illness.replace(repl_dict).groupby(df.drug_id)\
         .apply('|'.join).str.get_dummies().drop('CD', 1)

           FN  HD  MS
drug_id              
lexapro.1   0   1   1
lexapro.2   0   0   1
lexapro.3   0   1   0
lexapro.4   0   1   0
lexapro.5   1   1   0
```

Thank you!

Comment: Or `df.illness.replace(repl_dict).groupby(df.drug_id).apply('|'.join).str.get_dummies().drop('CD', 1)`

Answer (score 2):

Another way achieve this

```
pd.crosstab(df['drug_id'],df['illness']).rename(columns={'Sweat' : 'HD', 'WD': 'HD', 'HDED' : 'MS'}).groupby(lambda x : x,axis=1).sum().gt(0).astype(int).drop('CD',1)
Out[290]: 
           FN  HD  MS
drug_id              
lexapro.1   0   1   1
lexapro.2   0   0   1
lexapro.3   0   1   0
lexapro.4   0   1   0
lexapro.5   1   1   0
```